# how to insert Expanded in SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to insert a Expanded in SingleChildScrollView but not working.

Now I have this:

[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35, 130, 0, 0),
            child: Text(
              'Login',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 40,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: kBlueColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            ...
          ),
          Container(
            ...
          ),
          GestureDetector(
              ...
          ),
          Container(
            ...
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegistrationScreen()),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 24),
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: kButtonColor,
                ),
                child: Text('REGISTRAZIONE',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: kAzureDarkColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want that the Registration button stand down of page.
For example:
[image]

I try to use Expanded in SingleChildScrollView and I have a error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by combining a `LayoutBuilder`, your `SingleChildScrollView`, a `ConstrainedBox`, and two nested `Column`s with a `MainAxisAlignment` of `spaceBetween`:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 100,
                        color: Colors.amber,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 100,
                        color: Colors.purple,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 100,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                ],
              ), // your column
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a SingleChildScrollView? You could wrap everything with a Scaffold and put the Registration text in a ButtomNavigationBar.

```
   bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
         color: Colors.blue,
         child: Container(child: Text("Registration", style: 
     TextStyle(fontSize: 50),)),
    ),
```

[image]

[image]